# from numpy.distutils.core import Extension as Ext ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, build, setup.py, distutils

Y get the folowing error when trying to build my package (python -m build) with python3.x

```
 Setup.py

from numpy.distutils.core import Extension as Ext
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Answer (score 0):

Install `numpy` first by `pip install numpy` on in the terminal.

Comment: Y am using a conda env. I am installing numpy. But not resolved